# Spring Security's intercept-url's access="hasRole()" attribute gives error

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to use Spring security intercept-url for my api request to get Oauth2 security. But I am getting an error saying *Unsupported configuration attributes* whenever I try to use-

> access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"

*Please find below my version, configuration and error details:*

**A Versions:**

***1 Spring Version - 4.3.7.RELEASE***

***2 Spring Security Version - 4.2.2.RELEASE***

***3 JRE System Library - Java SE 1.8***

**B Spring XML Configuration:**

For my resources to be protected I have written following configuration:

```
<!-- Protected resources -->
<http pattern="/api/**"
      create-session="never" 
      use-expressions="true" 
      entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>

    <!-- Intercept your api requests to get the Oauth2 Security -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/addEmployee**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/getAllEmployees**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <custom-filter ref="corsHandler" after="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>

<!-- Authentication in config file -->
<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service id="userDetailsService">
            <user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<!-- Access Decision Manager Bean -->
<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

**C Server Error:**

When I build and run my project on Tomcat Server, I get following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN'), hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')]
>       at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:176)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
>       ... 47 more

Don't know why *hasRole()* is not working.

*Also, please find below the link to the Spring Security Reference html document:*

[Spring Security Reference 4.2.2 RELEASE](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/).

Help will be appreciated..

Comment: @dur, thanks for pointing out the link, that solved my issue. <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter" /> was missing.